# Can someone verify that this is an IE8 memory leak?

Tags: image, memory, internet-explorer-8, resize, memory-leaks

The leak is pretty easy to create. Place the HTML below alongside a list of large images named "TestImage0.jpg", "TestImage1.jpg",..."TestImage9.jpg". The page will leak memory (I used sIEve for testing) on every click of the page. If the resize css is removed, the page will not leak. Can anyone confirm that this is an IE8 problem, or that my experiment is flawed?

**Test Code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Memory Leak Testing</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var count = 0;

    window.onload =
        function() {
          AppendImage();
          window.document.body.onclick = ReplaceImage;
        }

    var ReplaceImage = function() {
      window.document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('MemTestObject' + count));
      count++;
      if (count > 9) {
        alert('No more images to load.');
      } else {    
        AppendImage();
      }
    }

    var AppendImage = function() {
      var imageObject = document.createElement('img');
      imageObject.id = 'MemTestObject' + count;
      imageObject.className = 'MemTestObject';
      imageObject.src = 'TestImage' + count + '.jpg';
      window.document.body.appendChild(imageObject);
    }

  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .MemTestObject {
      width: 140px;
      height: 178px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Memory Leak Testing</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested any other browsers?

Comment: The memory footprint of FF3 increases at about the same rate as IE8. However, FF3 releases the memory after waiting on a few garbage collection rounds. IE8 doesn't even release the memory when the page is unloaded.

Comment: Does it leak more memory if once you close the page and open it again it loads more?

Comment: Then again, caching is another form of memory leak, if the cache eviction is picked badly.

Answer (score 0):

The question is "Can someone verify that this is an IE8 memory leak?" To which the answer can only be, yes some one could verify this.

If you really think it is a valid memory leak in IE, first make sure that it is just IE. Then carry on working out specifics. Once you can describe exactly how to recreate this leak, you can consider reporting to MS, but they probably will not bother fixing it any time soon. But by all means spread the news so that others can avoid the trap